# lstlistings: Regexp quotation mark/apostrophe error

Tags: listings, python

I am attempting to display a long Python Regexp in LaTeX `lstlistings`. When compiling I get the following error message though.

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�\lst@FillFixed@\lst@EC� not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I believe it is caused by the quote marks ' and ´. How do I correctly display them in `lstlisting` the simplest way possible? I am a LaTeX beginner, and have searched and tried many other solutions, however none has helped me.

```
\lstset{
language=Python,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
captionpos=t,
texcl=true,
numbers=left,                    
numbersep=7pt,                   
showspaces=false,                
showstringspaces=false,          
showtabs=false,                  
stepnumber=1,   
breaklines=true,
}          

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, caption=Full source code]

pattern_p = re.finditer("(\t|; )((\w{2,}( |-)?)+) ?(\((m|f|n)\))? ?(\(((\w{2,}\'?-?’?\?? ?)+)(\)|,|’))?", decoded_line)

\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) always post MWEs that are things we can (attempt to) compile. Here we do not know the preamble. Are you sure you are not looking for `'` (the apostrophe) and ` (sometimes called the back ping). Those are ascii chars. When I copy your text those are UTF8 chars.

Comment: If I change those to ascii chars, then the code works fine.

Comment: Yes, those are UTF-8 chars because they are the ones I'm looking for with the Regexp.

Comment: `listings` does not like utf8 (it cannot handle 2bit chars very well). You might want to use `literate` in order to tell it how to handle those two chars.

Comment: This at least compiles: literate={’}{`}1  might want to use a different output symbol

Comment: Big thank you daleif! literate={’}{`}1 {ʹ}{`}1 in the lstset{} preamble did the trick. However, do you have any good suggestions for right-style single quote mark characters that it would accept?

Comment: Sorry. Have a look in the symbols list (on most systems available via `texdoc symbols-a4` or on CTAN

Comment: Found a good suggestion (\textquoteright) at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Thanks for the help daleif!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lstlistings does not work well with UTF-8. By adding

```
\lstset{
literate={’}{\textquoteright}1 {ʹ}{\textquoteright}1
}
```

The UTF-8 chars were replaced with close LaTeX produced counterparts.
Solution provided by daleif above.